# Range sharding or hash sharding

Tags: mongodb, neo4j, cassandra

I have a dating website where user interact between each other.

The data is like this:

```
ID Sender Receiver Msg      TIME
1   22     33      Hi       2017-04-01 
2   22     33      how r u  2017-04-02
3   33     22      i am gd  2017-04-03 
4   22     44      Hey      2017-04-03
```

Type of queries required:

1. List Sender=22 receivers
2. List Receiver=33 senders
3. Latest Sender=22 and receiver=33 Message
4. Archive old records say older than 3 years

How should I configure MongoDB sharding here?

Issues:

1. If I use range sharding :

   - All latest records will move to one shard, so it will be heavily used.
   - Also need to scan all shards to list any of above info
   - Helpful for archiving
2. If I use hash sharding :

   - Record distribution will be even
   - Also need to scan all shards to list any of above info
   - bad for archiving

Comment: Just an idea: because for such an application the relations of your data might be as important as the data itself you could also have a look at neo4j. I have never worked with it because I don't have any project that would benefit from it. But this would be a great example of something that might work really well with it.

Answer (score 1):

The efficiency of sharding is heavily dependent on the setup and amount of data. So if you really want an answer you need to test with representative data. However I can answer a bit about the idea and if it could help.

The idea for sharding is to have multiple machines work on a single query. The queries for the shards will finish quicker because the datasets are smaller, but if the time gain is smaller than the time needed to merge the results (say if you want a sort or a limited result) would determine if it is beneficial in your case.

I would not worry about something being "bad for achiving" since this is something you would probably only run once a week/month during some low traffic time. This way it should not interfere with day to day.

You should also test if this archiving is even needed. If you use the correct queries and limit results these old messages might not even have any effect on the performance.

Comment: i need all the requirement, the question whats the best way of sharding and even if mongodb is suitable for such need ?

Comment: what I am trying to tell you is that there is no "best" way. It depends on the data. You know the options, go and test them out!
As for if mongodb is suitable. In the end it is a document DB not a relational or graph db. If you have a very static schema without much nesting of data, perhaps postgreSQL is better suited. However if (as I said in my other comment) the data's relations are just as important as the data itself, hava a look at neo4j

Comment: I disagree with your idea that sharding is to have multiple machines working on a single query. That might be true if the number of shards is low. But the moment you get 10 servers for example, executing the same query in each of them is expensive.

Sharding is about being able to execute multiple queries simultaneously. If you have all the info from a user in one shard and from another user in another one, querying for both of them is easy and they are simple queries.

Comment: You are right, that is another way to use sharding. However, since the OP is about interaction between multiple users there is 0 guarantee that all those users are on the same shard and your query will still run on multiple shards.